# Not able to open sqlite database in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Finisar.SQLite;

namespace data_get
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
            SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
            SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

            sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=dataDb.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"))
            sqlite_conn.Open();
            sqlite_conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

~ Getting error on "sqlite_conn.Open();"

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll
>
> Additional information: unsupported file format

Comment: The message is clear, sqlite cant read the database it doesnt recognise the format.

Comment: Yes, but not understanding why it is showing this error. If i will use ".sqlite" than also it's shown this error.

Comment: Did you make the file or were you given it? did you rename the file?

Comment: I have created that file. and I haven't renamed it.

Comment: How did you make it?

Comment: I will just put name here "Data Source=dataDb.db" , In place of "dataDB.db", It will automatically create at the project location.

Comment: Is their anything that i want to change?